# Can an ecommerce site be moved to PWA gradually or needs to be written from scratch?

Tags: migration, e-commerce, progressive-web-apps

We're looking to migrate our ecommerce site to Progressive Web App (PWA). However, we don't know if it's too risky and even possible to gradually migrate website pages and pieces to PWA or it has to be done starting completely from scratch.

Any advice/resources on how a large scale ecommerce can be moved to PWA?

Comment: Since we do not know anything about the complexity of your site any answer we can give you would probably be wrong.

Comment: You can try :). It's a legacy system build 10 years ago using Apache Velocity for some pages and HTL (AEM) for other pages. I'm looking for some challenges to consider.

Comment: 10 years ago! That's a dinosaur. Rebuilding it would be faster. IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it. Here is no restrictions. Actually PWA is only manifest.json file and service worker. You can implement those fairly easily.

Challenges you will have (but you can solve them gradually):

- If you lunch PWA on mobile phone you will not have browser navigation. So you need to implement navigation by yourself, like native app do.
- Cache your files wisely. It easy to implement PWA with SPA because all you application in single file and you need to cache only a few files. If you have legacy code you may need to think twice what you want to cache and when. So, when you add PWA on our mobile phone you will have everything you need for proper app life.
- Offline. You should understand that user may launch your app without internet connection. Your app should be ready for this.